# apache conf Redirect not working

Tags: apache, document-root

So I have an apache .conf file that is working as expected except for one specific issue.  If I type in https://oaks.statehr.com it shows that I am in the true DocumentRoot of /var/www/statehr (see below) and everything works fine.

But if I enter http://oaks.statehr.com (no https), then I have two problems:

1. no redirect to https happens
2. the document root is /var/www vs. /var/www/statehr

Any idea why?  Here is the actual conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName oaks.statehr.com
Redirect / https://oaks.statehr.com/
DocumentRoot /var/www/statehr
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/statehr
ServerName oaks.statehr.com
<Directory "/var/www/statehr">
allow from all
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/www/statehr/sites/oaks/error/apache.error.log
CustomLog /var/www/statehr/sites/oaks/error/apache.access.log common
php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_log /var/www/statehr/sites/oaks/error/php.error.log
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" %P" wpid

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*.statehr.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*.statehr.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you resolved or not, but one thing you may consider trying is removing the double-quotes from around `<Directory "/var/www/statehr">`, as I have not seen that done in the past.